# How do create a Dynamic class in C# 4?

Tags: c#, dynamic

I want to create an object in C# and have it do interesting things based on the name of the non-existent method that gets.

In ruby, this is method_missing.  In Perl, this is AUTOLOAD.

I can't seem to find the way into System.Dynamic in C#.

Comment: @TStamper nothing *has* to be a wiki, it's up to the person whether they want reputation or share ownership of the question.

Comment: @Rex M- True..it was just to inform the person since they seem to not be an active person on SO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [System.Dynamic.DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject(VS.100).aspx) as a simple starting point and base class. You can find an example at http://winterdom.com/2009/05/dynamicobject-in-c-40.