# Dynamically create type and call constructor of base-class

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit, ilgenerator

I need to create a class dynamically. Most things work fine but i'm stuck in generating the constructor.

```
AssemblyBuilder _assemblyBuilder =
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("MyBuilder"),                                                        AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);

ModuleBuilder _moduleBuilder = _assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MyModule");

public static object GetInstance<TSource, TEventArgs>(this TSource source, string eventName)
    where TSource : class
{
    var typeName = "MyTypeName";
    var typeBuilder = _moduleBuilder.DefineType(typeName, TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.Public);

    // create type like class MyClass : GenericType<MyClass, TSource, TEventArgs>
    var baseNotGenericType = typeof(GenericType<,,>);
    var baseType = baseNotGenericType.MakeGenericType(typeBuilder, typeof(TSource), typeof(TEventArgs)); 
    typeBuilder.SetParent(baseType);


    // the base class contains one constructor with string as param
    var baseCtor = baseNotGenericType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new[] { typeof(string) }, null);

    var ctor = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.Standard | CallingConventions.HasThis, new Type[0]);
    var ilGenerator = ctor.GetILGenerator();

    // i want to call the constructor of the baseclass with eventName as param
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // push "this"
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, eventName); // push the param
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, baseCtor);
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    var type = typeBuilder.CreateType();

    // return ...
}
```

On call of the constructor i'm getting a BadImageFormatException. What am i doing wrong?

As requested:

The BaseClass looks something like this:

```
public abstract class GenericType<GT, TEventSource, TEventArgs> : BaseClass
    where GT: GenericType<GT, TEventSource, TEventArgs>, new()
    where TEventArgs : EventArgs
    where TEventSource : class
{
    protected GenericType(string eventName)
    {
        _eventName = eventName;
    }
    // ...
}
```

What i would like to have as a result in runtime:

```
public class MyType : BaseClass<MyType, ConcreteSourceType, ConcreteEventArgsType>
{
    protected MyType() : base("SomeName")
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893423/how-do-create-a-dynamic-class-in-c-sharp-4

Comment: Not really helpful or did i miss something? I want to inherit from a baseclass and call it's base constructor which have an argument.

Comment: Try this link as well http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cburrows/archive/2009/04/22/dynamic-base-classes-in-c-4.aspx

Comment: This link is about a dynamic as baseclass. I need a dynamically generated subclass from a predefines generic baseclass.

Comment: How do the generic parameters work here? Is this code in a class (or method) that has generic parameters `TSource` and `TSource`?

Comment: I edit the question to answer your question. I let out the return statement because i am accessing some static property and so on; just to keep it simple.

Comment: please paste the desired class definition also in regular C# to make the question clearer (i.e. what the class would look like if you defined it declaratively.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're trying to call the constructor of the open generic type `GenericType<GT, TEventSource, TEventArgs>`, but you need to call the constructor of the closed type `BaseClass<MyType, ConcreteSourceType, ConcreteEventArgsType>`. The solution to the seems simple:

```
var baseCtor = baseType.GetConstructor(
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null,
    new[] { typeof(string) }, null);
```

The problem is that this doesn't work and throws `NotSupportedException`. So, it seems getting the constructor of a generic type, where one of the parameters is a `TypeBuilder` is nut supported.

Because of that, I think what you want is not possible using Reflection.Emit, unless there is some hack to work around this.

**EDIT:** A-HA! I had to dive deep into Reflection.Emit in Reflector <sub><sup>(although looking at the right place in the documentation would have worked too)</sup></sub>, but I found it: there is a special method exactly for this: [the static `TypeBuilder.GetConstructor()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145822.aspx).  So this should work:

```
var baseNonGenericCtor = baseNotGenericType.GetConstructor(
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null,
    new[] { typeof(string) }, null);
var baseCtor = TypeBuilder.GetConstructor(baseType, baseNonGenericCtor);
```

Comment: So i am looking forward to see a hack :)

Comment: Actually, it is possible and it's not a hack at all, see edit.

Comment: BTW, questions like this that make me learn something new are the best.

Comment: No credit to me for suggesting reflection.emit language in reflector?

Comment: How do you activate and get your instance from this?

Comment: @Wobbles Call [the `Invoke()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ycw1y17).

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do this would be to compile up your abstract and derived classes into a simple assembly, then open them in Reflector using the "Reflection.Emit" language available as a addin from:

http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/

[image: Reflector: Reflection.Emit language]

Yes, that's as cool as it sounds :)

Comment: If your desired class definition is valid c# and will compile, then yes.

Comment: Well, the code it generates in this case doesn't make much sense and wouldn't help the OP. That's because it uses `typeof(MyType)`, which doesn't make sense when you're building that type. And using `typeBuilder` instead would lead to a `NotSupportedException`.

Comment: Good point... I see that now. I guess recursive parametric types are going to be tough. :)

Comment: Sorry for late "credit" :) I'm still trying if it really works. But thanks for the idea!