# Entity Framework DbContext dynamic instantiation with custom Connection String

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

Migrating from ObjectContext to DbContext code-generation, I realized that context class generated (which inherits from DbContext) has no constructor that receives **connectionString** neither **EntityConnection** (like ObjectContext child class had).

This is a problem in my application since I need to instantiate my context dynamically from the concrete Type, using a runtime generated connection string.

Answer (score 1):

On your class that inherits the DbContext, you should be able to specify the base constructor that takes the connection sting:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(string connString)
        : base(connString)
    {
    }
}
```

You will have to use the SQLConnection builder though:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder connBuilder= new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(dbConnString);
```

And use it in your constructor:

```
MyDbContext dbContext = new MyDbContext(connBuilder.ToString());
```

Comment: Hi Ezakiel! That's the more logical way to do it. But I can't modify my class MyDbContext adding that constructor. ObjectContext suited my needs in this providing out of the box constructor with connection string, can't believe this was no considered in DbContext

Comment: Edited response and added "partial" to the class definiton resolve your issue; now you haven't to edit the generated code

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be generated right out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

```
 public MyDatabaseContext():base("name=MyConnectionString")
  {
  }
```