# How to create a class with a given name c#

Tags: c#, class

I would like to create a class with the name passed in the function. How do I do that?

Basically what I mean is:
we have a function called

```
public void CreateClassWithThisName(string name)
{

}
```

and then we create a class

```
class name
{
   //this name is the one passed as parameter in function CreateClassWithThisName
   private Id {get;set}
}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen to the class after its "created"?

Comment: Is the class in the same assembly, or where is it located?

Comment: I think he wants the class to be created on runtime.

Comment: not sure about your intentions, but if you need something like this. you are prolly doing something wrong.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [How do create a Dynamic class in C# 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893423/how-do-create-a-dynamic-class-in-c-sharp-4)?

Comment: @DarthVader +1 from me... but with the following caveat "AND if you don't already know how to do it".

Answer (score 5):

I assume you mean you want to create an *instance* of the class with the given name. You can use:

```
Type type = Type.GetType(name);
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

However, note that:

- `name` must be a fully qualified type name, including namespace
- Either the type has to be in mscorlib or the executing assembly, *or* `name` has to be an assembly-qualified type name
- This assumes there's a public parameterless constructor in the target type; there are other overloads of [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) to specify constructor arguments

You could also use `Assembly.GetType(string)` to fetch a type from a specific assembly.