# MVC Dynamic Model to dynamic view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to develop an mvc page that upfront  we don't know what model to use until certain conditions are met. When we have the model needed, the view has to resemble that information.

Since we are using MVC 4 and using models with lambda notation we can't render every property from the model because all of them have different properties with different variable types and we need to use only one view and one controller to accomplish this.

I implemented dynamic classes but got stuck when trying to render the view since I don't know what properties will there be nor the names they have.

Any pointers how to get this done or tutorials out there that explain this situation.

Comment: Do you have any code samples? What is dynamic classes?

Comment: @Kunukn lets you define operations which do net yet exist. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893423/how-do-create-a-dynamic-class-in-c-sharp-4

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answers your question, but you can specify both what model you want to send, and what view you want to send it to, without really doing anything too fancy:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    var model1 = new Model1();
    var model2 = new Model2();

    if (id == 1)
    {
        return View("ViewForModel1", model1);
    }

    if (id == 2)
    {
        return View("ViewForModel2", model2);
    }

    // if it gets this far, return index
    return View();
}
```

MSDN:  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460310(v=vs.118).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460310%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: he wants `only one view`, which i have no idea how you'd do.  This is the approach i'd take.

Comment: to me this is the only logical approach :)

Comment: this will be good if there were a fixed set of views and models, but a user can create a "model" for some random operation, a different user must be able to look that new "model" and persist data.

Comment: I wonder if jquery and ajax would the trick...I'll update on this later

Comment: Allowing a user to create a model is not MVC.  I think you should create an abstraction that supports something like a model.  It seems you are trying to create a "form builder" or something of that nature, which has been done many times before via an abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

This is messy. But if your view takes a `dynamic` model you could do something like this in your view:

```
   @model dynamic

   @if(Model is Model1)
    {
      ...
      return;
    }

    @if(Model is Model2)
    {
      ...
      return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In general if you want something dynamic it might be best to do things in a weakly typed fashion.  You might want to avoid using the lambda helpers and instead use the weakly typed html helper counter parts.  You can get the property names using reflection or the model meta data engine.  You might also want to take a look at Dynamic MVC.

http://dynamicmvc.com